# Using SaltStack, how can I watch for *one* file change in a git repository?

Tags: salt-stack

For example, I have a [git.latest](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.git.html#salt.states.git.latest) state like this:

```
foobar:
  git.latest:
    - branch: production
    ...
```

I want to define a `cmd.run` or `cmd.wait` state that runs if and only if ***one*** particular file in the foobar git repository has changed. I don't care if other files of the repo have changed.

How can I do that?

There doesn't seem to be anything immediately obvious in the current release of SaltStack (2015.8.4)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Github (or similar), you could use `file.managed` to watch the file for changes:

```
/tmp/egg:
  file.managed:
    - source: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mafrosis/dotfiles/master/README.md
    - source_hash: sha1=bf5b231d1b3dc9bc3217896f9f5d1c903b0779dd
  cmd.wait:
    - name: touch /tmp/bacon
    - watch:
      - file: /tmp/egg
```

Answer (score 0):

You could dump the files git is going to change into a 'changed_files' file, then check for the file you want to check:

```
update_git:
  cmd.run:
    - name: git fetch && git --no-pager diff --no-color --name-only HEAD origin/{{ branch }} > /tmp/changed_files
    - cwd: {{ directory }}
  git.latest:
    - name: {{ git_url }}
    - branch: {{ git_branch }}
    - target: {{ directory }}

update_npm_packages:
  cmd.run:
    - name: npm ci --only=production --unsafe-perm
    - cwd: {{ directory }}
    - onlyif: test `/tmp/changed_files | grep package-lock.json | wc -l` != 0
    - require:
        - cmd: update_git
```